# How to pass json object as a parameter to another method

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I'm using two jsp one for searching the records and another for updating the records of the database. Search query will return a json object where it contain all the searched records and I'm generating the rows dynamically to a table for displaying. To update a record, I've kept link in every row. 
         Here I have to pass the json object to the updating jsp file to load the values. So, I simply passed the json object. But, I cannot process the json object. Help me out. Thanks. Please Find the code below:

```
function retrievesrchrec(){                 
    var result = xmlHttp.responseText;
    if(result.length>1){
        var dbRecords = JSON.parse(result);
        if(dbRecords)
        {
            while(dbRecords[index])
            {
                dbRecord= dbRecords[index];
                var rbutton = document.createElement("input");
                rbutton.type = "a";
                rbutton.href = function(){
                    javascript:loadModify(jsonobj);
                };

            }
        }
    }
}
function loadmodify(jsonobj){
    alert(jsonobj);
}
```

Comment: similar question on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829643/processing-json-objects-in-jsp

Comment: Some more details are needed, like whether you use the data on the server side or on the client side, and what kind of data it really is. JSON data is not an object, it's a string, so do you have an object, or do you have JSON?

Comment: I've parsed and I'm iterating the json returned. Everything is done through javascript only. Please see the code

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(result);`?

Comment: Just Object[Object] for printing the jsonobj. When I tried to retrieve the content jsonobj["ID"]. I got undefined as the value.

Comment: @Nila that does not answer my question

Comment: [{"MainDBName":"sampledb","EnvLabel":"BB","AnalyticsDB_ID":"DB001","EngineID":"EC002","EnvType":"bp","blockDiagramView":"VSBlockDiagram/VSBD","EnvStatus":"null","EngineName":"Testing Dummy","EnvDesc":"Dummy Place","EnvID":"EV002","itView":"VStoreIT/VStoreIT","NetCoolLog":"Yes","EnvName":"Dummy Piece","EnvLocation":"Dummy","EnvEmailID":"dummy@jimmy.com","MainDB_ID":"DB002","HealthReportDuration":"60","AnalyticsDBName":"emapit_103","NotificationSupressionInterval":"3600","TimeZone":"null"},{"MainDBName":"sampledb","EnvLabel":"CC"}]

Comment: (1) Is it the full object or you trimmed id because it's repeating the pattern? The second object is **much** shorter than the first. (2) Where do you define `index`? (3) You don't seem to have a `index++` anywhere (4) add an `alert("modify");` as the first line in your `loadmodify(...)` function so you know if it reaches there

Comment: It appears you have a stray "-" after "EnvName".

Comment: I'e posted the code just for the flow and in my sourcebase it is fine with all the questions u've asked. Sorry for that. My issue is to get the jsonobj to the method loadmodify. That's it. I cannot access the content of the json passed in the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JSON object is not more than a regular javascript object. It should work if you pass it as a parameter to a function. The problem is somewhere else.

Try this version:

```
function retrievesrchrec(){                 
    var result = xmlHttp.responseText;
    if(result.length>1){
        var dbRecords = JSON.parse(result);
        if(dbRecords)
        {
            var index=0;
            while(dbRecords[index])
            {
                dbRecord= dbRecords[index];
                var rbutton = document.createElement("A");
                rbutton.href = loadModify(dbRecord);
                index++;
             }
        }
    }
}
function loadModify(jsonobj){
    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonobj));
    alert(jsonobj.EnvLabel);
    return "http:\/\/www.example.com";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But, still same output I'm getting. 'Undefined'

Comment: Well, it's `rbutton.href = loadModify(dbRecord);`, not `rbutton.href = loadModify(jsonObj);` :/ Fixed. It *should* work.

Comment: Yes. But, I'm getting undefined as the value here.

Comment: I just pasted it into a jsfiddle. [Check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/uJd2C/). It works just fine.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I just converted json to string while passing the parameter of loadmodify and the I can access now inside the loadmodify. Thanks.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JSONService.asmx/TestJSON",
                data: '{"Name":"mohammad","Company":"Faraconesh"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
});
```

and in service code

```
public string TestJSON(string Name,string Company)
    {
        Employee e = new Employee();

        e.Name = Name;
        e.Company = Company;}
```

`Name` & `Company` in my method is my jason abject value

Answer (score 0):

Potential problems that I can see in the code you posted:

Where is the 'index' variable from the while loop declared, initialised and incremented/updated?

Within the while loop you are trying to create an 'input' element of type 'a' and with an 'href' attribute - both of which are not valid for 'input' elements. Perhaps you really should be creating an 'a' element?

Assuming you did have an a element, doesn't the 'href' attribute have to be a string? You're assigning it to point to a function.

Your 'loadmodify()' function is declared all in lowercase but called with a capital 'M'.

Comment: I'm really sorry. The function which I have posted is just for the understanding of the flow and moreover, it is working fine in all the browsers. Now my issue is I cannot get the jsontext from the parameter.

Comment: Well I'm all for only posting cut-down versions of code, but as Felix said you need to be sure the cut-down version doesn't introduce more problems than the part you're trying to ask about.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code is very wrong:

```
var rbutton = document.createElement("input");
rbutton.type = "a";
rbutton.href = function(){
    javascript:loadModify(jsonobj);
};
```

1. You create an `<input>` element at set its `type` to `a`. This type does not exist. It has either to be `text`, `password`, hidden, `button`, `submit` or `reset`.
2. It seems you think you created a link now, as you are trying to set the `href` attribute. Two things are wrong here:

   1. An `<input>` element has no `href` attribute.
   2. The value of an `href` attribute has to be a **string**, not a function.
3. The label `javascript:` is unnecessary here.
4. You are passing `jsonobj` to the function, but you never define it anywhere.

I think it is better you create a `<button>` and assign a `click` handler:

```
var rbutton = document.createElement("button");
rbutton.append(document.createTextNode('Click me!')); // you need some text
rbutton.onclick = function(){
    loadModify(dbRecord); // pass dbRecord here
};
```

Comment: Please.. Ignore the code. It is just for understanding the flow. It is working. I've posted only partial code. Sorry. My issue is to get the json object value in load modify method.

Comment: @Nila: Well, even if you post partial code, you have to post **correct** code. How should we know where the exact problem is otherwise? Please provide a minimal working example that reproduces your problem.