# How to use JSON response for clone tables?

Tags: ajax, json, jstl

Here my code consists 2 fields(1.select field, 2.input filed),i am displaying data into these fields based on id's (using json data through ajax call)like ($("#allergictoId").val(data.allergy.allergicTo1)).Now my requirement changed like if i click on button (save and add allergy)the copy of that is added to previous code.Once he added clones and clicks on save the entire data will saved on database.Now he clicks again edit i can display the entire data with clones jsp code.Here is my jsp code

```
<div id="divHideAllergies" class="clone">
    <div class="copy">
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="portlet box carrot ">
                <div class="portlet-title">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <i class="fa fa-medkit"></i> Allergies
                    </div>
                </div>
           <div class="portlet-body form">
                <div class="form-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="control-label col-md-3">Allergy Type:</label>
                          <div class="col-md-9">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-medkit"></i></span>
                                   <select  class="form-control" id="allergy_type">
                                        <option selected value="">--Select One--</option>
                                             <option value="Drug">Drug</option>
                                             <option value="Environmental">Environmental</option                                                                                    <option value="Food">Food</option>
                                   </select>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Allergic to:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-medkit"></i></span>
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first name" id="allergictoId"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div><a class="btn btn-lg green pull-right" id="addallergy">Save and Add Allergy <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-lg red" id="removeallergy"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel</a>                                         
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What's the problem with the JSON response? Why is jQuery tagged, what's it's role?

Comment: I can't understand anything. You must create a table using the JSTL to display the content of a JSON response, but you may not use the JSON response? It doesn't make any sense to me. BTW, I see no JSON at all in what you posted, and no attemps at creating a table either.

Comment: I need to display json object data into this html fields dynamically.here my html code has 2 fields, i mean that if json object has 2 records,now i need to create 4 fields dynamically and displayed those records into these fields.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I can understand your question at 100% but here are some thoughts:

Check the "[Processing JSON objects in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829643/processing-json-objects-in-jsp)" question. Here they are using scriptlets but you can do basically the same with JSTL.

Your JSP seems to have lack of JSP code in it - it is just a HTML - and that's fine, but you can consider using JavaScript to process you JSON response since it is so much natural (at least to me).

Comment: I need to display json object data into this html fields dynamically.here my html code has 2 fields, i mean that if json object has 2 records,now i need to create 4 fields dynamically and displayed those records into these fields.

Comment: First tell me:  Where is your JSON? how do you access it?

Comment: $.ajax({
 contentType : "application/json",
 dataType : 'json',
 cache : false,
 type : "GET",
 url : getAllergies,
 success : function(data) {}
Now the data object has 2 records ,allergies: Array[2]
0: Object
allergicTo: "Allergic to1"
allerigyType: "Drug"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
allergicTo: "Allergic to2"
allerigyType: "Environmental"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]  Now i need to display this object data into those fields,it will vary every time.

Comment: Generally i use to display this fields based on Id's like ($("#allergictoId1").val(data.allergy.allergicTo1);).here it is single record so i didn't get any problem later requirement was changed to clone table.How many records we are saved into the database,that number of records are displayed using this type of  jsp code. I hope you understand my question, if not i can explain again once

Comment: The main theme of this Question is how to disply json object in the jsp page.

Comment: Include this info in your question, please. Apart from that - I still don't understand what is the problem of using the already included jQuery to achieve the task.  
Give us more context so we can help you.

Comment: Here my code consists 2 fields(1.select field, 2.input filed),i am displaying data into these fields based on id's like ($("#allergictoId1").val(data.allergy.allergicTo1)).Here now i added 2 buttons,1.save and add allergy ,2.cancel. If i click on first button (save and add allergy)the copy of that is added to previous code.Once he added clones and clicks on save the entire data will saved on database.Now he clicks again edit i can display the entire data with clones.