# how to pass a list from the servlet to a ajax call

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have a servlet list:

```
String appname=request.getParameter("AppID");
System.out.println("Entered ajax request 1 : Get list");
List<Object> li = Model.getList(appname);
// enter your code here
```

I have an AJAX call which is taking that list from the servlet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#app-name').change(function () {
        var applname=$(this).value();
        $.ajax({
              url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/rollreturn',
              data: {AppID:applname},
              success: function(data){
                  var order_data = data;
                  $('#roll-name').html('');
                  $.each(order_data, function(i, item) {
                      $('<option value='+ order_data[i] +'>'+order_data[i]).html('</options>').appendTo('#roll-name');
                  });
              }
        });
    });
});
```

How can I pass the list to the AJAX call. Can you help me with this?

Also can you tell me whether the AJAX call I have written is correct or not?

Comment: XML OR JSON is the standard way for transferring data to and fro . So pack your list data nto a JSON and send it to ajax call . For using JSON API you need to use any third party JSON jars

Comment: @PreethiJain why do we need any third party JAR?

Comment: @Khan From where are you getting this class new Gson().

Comment: @UnKnown its a google library you will get it from, http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm

Comment: @khAn , that is nothing but third party JAR?

Answer (score 0):

By setting the content type in servlet.

```
response.setContentType("application/json");

new Gson().toJson(li, response.getWriter());
```

result in ajax you will receive an JSON object so you have to parse it.

There are many ways of parsing JSON object in JSP/HTML file.
A simple example

[See Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/json/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_parse)

You can also parse your JSON object using JSTL tag and scriplet tag.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829643/processing-json-objects-in-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use OutputStream to write list values from servlet

To download gson jar [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm)

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

In your doGet/doPost method

```
ArrayList<Object> listresult=new ArrayList<Object>();

listresult.add("values1");
listresult.add("values2");
listresult.add("values3");
listresult.add("values4");

response.setContentType("application/json");
OutputStream outputStream= response.getOutputStream();
Gson gson=new Gson();       
outputStream.write(gson.toJson(listresult).getBytes());
outputStream.flush();
```

To retrieve values in ajax success function

```
success: function(result){
for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
{           
 alert(result[i]);
}
},
```

Answer is too late, It helps some others